# Centering the X-Axis of an SSRS line chart at zero

Tags: reporting-services, charts

What I'm trying to do is create a line-chart. Because the lines are equally located above and below the zero line, I'd like to move the X-Axis to the zero line, rather than underneath the number line. I know it's possible in Excel, and that's what I'm trying to emulate in an SSRS report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go into the Properties Window for the Y-Axis and set the CrossAt property to: =0

Answer (score 0):

The disadvangtage of this method is that lines and especially bars might be blocking the labels on the x-axis. In that case it might be preferable to create a dark line at 0, but keep the numbers below the graph instead. For this you can use a Stripline.

- Click the labels on the y-axis within the chart. In the properties (you won't find it under right click!) look for StripLines under Appearance and press the ... button.
- Click Add and change the borderstyle and colour as preferred. Standard settings are sufficient. Click Ok.
- Now hide the current x-axis line. Right click on the x-axis labels en go to the properties and Line to select line style: none.